Access installed managed package version from external system
I have a managed package which orgs can install. The creates some custom objects in which I sync some data from an external system (I have done OAuth integration using which I create/update my custom objects in sf)
There are some objects which are present in my latest managed package version but not in the older one, so I have handled sync for these based on whether the package installed by customer have version > x.xx or not.
But currently I have to ask the customer and manually store the package version they are using in my database.
Going forward I want to automate this such that either I fetch the package version through some rest call and populate that in my database (could have a job scheduled at some frequency doing this), or when package is installed/upgraded I receive a call from the sf org with the current package version (I have not much explored the post install/upgrade script option in sf package yet).
To fetch package version, I found following soql call that can be done using tooling Api:
SELECT Id, SubscriberPackageId, SubscriberPackage.NamespacePrefix,
    SubscriberPackage.Name, SubscriberPackageVersion.Id,
    SubscriberPackageVersion.Name, SubscriberPackageVersion.MajorVersion,
    SubscriberPackageVersion.MinorVersion,
    SubscriberPackageVersion.PatchVersion,
    SubscriberPackageVersion.BuildNumber 
FROM InstalledSubscriberPackage 
ORDER BY SubscriberPackageId

But the limitation to this is that I will need the Download AppExchange Packages permission for the user with which my customer is doing the auth integration, this could be a potential security concern for the customer, and they may not agree for this (kindly provide feedback on whether it is really a big deal to provide this permission or it is not that big of an issue).
Edit: I already checked; this permission is too permissive to assign to the integration user, need some other solution.
Let me know if there could be other solutions to achieve this.
I thought about creating a new custom object for which I may create/update the record in post install/upgrade script which would contain the package version (yet to explore if it is doable), and later I fetch this from rest Api call. But even, if possible, it would only solve the problem going forward, for existing packages I would still have to manually confirm the package version customers are using and populate in db.

You can get basic detail (the patch version does not query as anything other than 0) using the standard SOQL queryable Publisher object, as discussed here.

Thanks Phil, I checked this, and it seems to be working fine with the limited permissions my current integration user is having. But still did not find it anywhere in the documentations that what permissions are required to fetch this, do you have any idea about that? (+ it still misses the patch number)

I actually do not know which permissions, if any, are required since I only ever queried it through Apex, which can ignore permissions.
